# Publishing a private iOS app - Clarifications

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing an iOS app that is going to be used internally within our organization, and do not intend to publish it to the App Store.

I have some elementary questions to which I can't seem to get correct answers despite some research.

Since the company owns the code, in which name should an Apple ID be created? 
Once the app is ready to be deployed to the device, in whose name should I purchase the developer program? 
Should I go for the corporate purchase where it asks for DUNS number of the corporation? In such cases, should I rely on the purchase departmentof my company to make the actual purchase?

Also, how do I sign the app? I believe it asks for an email id to generate the key. Can this ID be mine? 
Finally, How do I add more team members who can support or add new features to the app in my absence? 
How can I provide them access to build the app (code signing).

The intention is to have an ID to test the app in real devices. The test machines are in Country 1 and Country 2. So, if I purchase the ID from Country 1, can I use the same ID to test the devices in Country 2 too. Is there any restriction in doing that?

We would like to test the app in iPhone and iPAD. Is there a limitation in number of devices to be added to a developer ID?

We have an apple ID in Country 1 and another apple ID in Country 2, since we have two Mac machines, 1st in Country 1 and 2nd in Country 2. Whether both apple IDs can use the same developer ID?

Appreciate the answers and sorry for the long list of questions.

Thanks,
Mathew Liju

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three choices: With a "normal" developer account, you can manually install an app on a reasonably large number of devices; I think it is about 100. Usually this is used to give an app to testers. With a "corporate" developer account, you can distribute an app on all devices owned by your company. Your company has to sign some contracts; you are not allowed to distribute outside your company. And with a "normal" developer account again, you can put the app on the app store. However, anyone can then download it, and Apple will be testing it and can reject it.

Up to 20 or 50 devices I'd go with the "normal" developer account. I have one private account, and one belonging to the company - your company should probably buy one "normal" developer account and then any developers in the company can use it. You can always start with that account, and if the number of users grows, buy a corporate account.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need the corporate purchase where it asks for DUNS number of the corporation.
You will be able to make ipa files that aren't tied to specific devices.
Also for testing you will be able adhoc builds.
You will not be able make builds for App Store.
All other is the same as with developer program.

Comment: Additional details: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html